# How did law enforcement recover fingerprints from the "blue cheese encrochat picture"

Tags: image-processing, image-analysis, photo

I hope that my question suits well within the topics discussed in this SE website. It was reported some time ago how a man

> was identified after he shared the photo on the encrypted messaging service EncroChat, from which police were able to analyse his fingerprints.

and again:

> His palm and fingerprints were analysed from this picture and it was established they belonged to

the man. ([Feeling blue: drug dealer’s ‘love of stilton’ leads to his arrest](https://www.theguardian.com/food/2021/may/24/feeling-blue-drug-dealers-love-of-stilton-leads-to-his-arrest)).

The article I quote also provide the picture: but his fingerprints are very blurry, to the extent that it looks impossible to recover identifying data from there! (On the other hand, I could believe that perhaps the creases of the palm may prove useful for identification purposes). What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the picture in the article doesn’t have the quality of the original? It is very common for websites to downsample and compress images. The man might have shared a picture where the fingerprints showed sufficient detail.

Comment: [Forensics officers enhanced the image](https://www.theguardian.com/food/2021/may/24/feeling-blue-drug-dealers-love-of-stilton-leads-to-his-arrest#:~:text=Forensics%20officers%20enhanced%20the%20image)

Comment: @Bob what is your comment suppose to mean?

Comment: That some (possibly manual) treatment was made to the image before they could identify the finger prints. That probably includes subtracting a moving average or something like that to increase contrast. And that was done on the original image not the image in the paper.